# Jquery Model Window + DataGridview TemplateField

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a gridview on my Page. I want to open a jquery dialog on the click of the linkButton placed inside the itemtemplate of the gridview. I`ve added the js and css files on my master.aspx page. But still it doesnt open.

My Jquery CODE:

```
 $('#gvLCStatus ContentPlaceHolder1_gvLCStatus_lnkbtnShipment_0').dialog({

    create: function (event, ui) { }
('ContentPlaceHolder1_gvLCStatus_lnkbtnShipment_0').bind("dialogcreate", function (event, ui) {
});
});
```

MY Gridview ItemTemplate Field:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnShipment" runat="server">Shipment Status</asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

I want to Open a Jquery Dialog on the click of this item template field.

Answer (score 0):

Use `OnClientClick` like this.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnShipment" runat="server" OnClientClick="return YourFunction(Parameter)')>Shipment Status</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: what do i write in function name? and what to pass in parameter?

Comment: see a sample : http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_imagebutton_onclientclick.asp